# Creating logs in c#

Tags: c#, .net, logging, cruisecontrol.net

I am creating logs in C# by using object of ILog in log4net. I am passing two parameters 1) repository where it will create log file 2)name of log file but it is showing exception that directory is not defined and if I do it by just passing name of log file ,program runs successfully but I am unable to find the log file.

Here is my code :-

```
private void createLogger(string Logdirectory)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(Logdirectory))
            {
                Log = LogManager.GetLogger( Logdirectory , LogFilename);

            }
            else
            {
                Log = LogManager.GetLogger(LogFilename);

            }
        }
```

Here is console output :-

[image]
**Help me find suitable way of getting logger by Ilog or by any other method except filestream**

Comment: Step through your code to see what LogFileName is. Also, you might be concatenating a full filename path with logdirectory, repeating the directory name in the string

Comment: The way you do it cannot work. The string arguments of the LogManager.GetLogger(...) method do not specify log file names nor directories. Read the Log4Net documentation what the purpose of those string arguments is. To write log messages to a file, you will need to setup a so-called FileAppender. See the Log4Net documentation or one of the blog articles/tutorials about this topic (like [this one](https://codingsexy.wordpress.com/2013/07/07/log4net-code/) or [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial))

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation, log4net is very configurable and well documented.

Documentation: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

```
using Com.Foo; // Import log4net classes.
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;
public class MyApp
{ // Define a static logger variable so that it references the // Logger instance named "MyApp".
  private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyApp));
  static void Main(string[] args)
  { // Set up a simple configuration that logs on the console.
   BasicConfigurator.Configure();
   log.Info("Entering application.");
   Bar bar = new Bar();
   bar.DoIt();
   log.Info("Exiting application.");
 }
}
```

Take note the difference in the method for getting to log instance.

1. You're asking for an ILog for the current Type not an explicitly a filename
2. You're telling log4net to read configuration settings from the app.config/web.config
3. Depending on your config you may need to use the XmlConfigurator

An example of the .config file is:

```
<log4net> <!-- A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender -->
 <appender name="A1" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender"> <!-- A1 uses PatternLayout -->
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout"> 
   <conversionPattern value="%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
 </appender>
<!-- Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1 -->
 <root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="A1" />
 </root>
</log4net>
```

There are lots of Appenders, above is a ConsoleAppender, but a DatabaseAppender exists and other types that might fit with you're need.